# Group dates by month in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm currently trying to organize data of avocado prices that was used in Sentdex data analysis video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DamIIzp41Jg&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfSfqQuee6K8opKtZsh7sA9&index=2

Here is the dataset that I am using: https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices

I want to group the dates for the state of California  by the month to ultimately graph month with average price.

I've currently written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(avocado.csv")

cali = pd.DataFrame()

region_df = df.copy()[ df['region'] == "California" ]


cali = region_df[["Date","AveragePrice"]]

M=["Jan",'Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

cali = region_df[["Date","AveragePrice"]]

cali["Month"] = "NA"


cali.loc[cali.Date.str.contains('2015-01'), 'Month'] = M[0]

cali.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

cali.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

This is the output for the table:

[table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csRHn.jpg)

To do this for every month from 2015 to 2018 would be messy and tedious, I was wondering if there is a more efficient method to group dates by month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), with convert `Date` to `DatetimeIndex` in `read_csv` if need plot `year with month`s:

```
df = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv", index_col=['Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])

region_df = df[df['region'] == "California" ]
s = region_df.resample('MS').AveragePrice.mean()
print (s)

s.plot()
```

If need plot months like `Jan, Feb...`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv", index_col=['Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])

region_df = df[df['region'] == "California" ].copy()
region_df = region_df.sort_index()

s = region_df.groupby(region_df.index.strftime('%b'), sort=False).AveragePrice.mean()
print (s)
Date
Jan    1.218333
Feb    1.191875
Mar    1.281765
Apr    1.306923
May    1.263929
Jun    1.360000
Jul    1.502857
Aug    1.583462
Sep    1.626250
Oct    1.723929
Nov    1.527308
Dec    1.298846
Name: AveragePrice, dtype: float64

d.plot()
```

Comment: Thank-you very much, does pretty much what I wanted with minimal code. What would I do If I wanted to graph by month without averaging the prices for each month.

Comment: @Nexusapp106 - Not sure if understand, what  should be in axis=x and axis=y?

Comment: @Nexusapp106 - Or need after `region_df = region_df.sort_index()` use `region_df.AveragePrice.plot()` ?

Comment: Omitting .mean() to give s = region_df.resample('MS').AveragePrice the plotted data gives axisx = date and axisy = price, but I want axisx = month.

Comment: @Nexusapp106 - So need after `region_df = region_df.sort_index()` use `region_df['month'] = region_df.index.strftime('%b')` and then plot by `month` column in `axis=x` and  `AveragePrice` in `axis=y` ?

Comment: then use `region_df.set_index('month').AveragePrice.plot()`, but months are duplicated, because no aggregation

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind creating new columns on your data frame you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = [
    {'Date': '2015-12-27', 'AveragePrice': 1.33, 'TotalVolume': 64236.62},
    {'Date': '2015-08-26', 'AveragePrice': 2.66, 'TotalVolume': 900},
    {'Date': '2015-08-5', 'AveragePrice': 2.34, 'TotalVolume': 900}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
df['Month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['Year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)

df.groupby(['Month', 'Year']).sum(['AveragePrice', 'TotalVolume'])
```

[photo of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNQVg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You parse the column '**Date**' data to the month in name by **converting** the **datatype** of '**Date**' values to **datetime64**.

```
df = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
cali = pd.DataFrame()
region_df = df.copy()[ df['region'] == "California" ]
cali = region_df[["Date","AveragePrice"]]

# Convert column 'Date' values data type to dtype='datetime64[ns]'
cali['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(cali['Date']).month_name()
print(cali.head())

#  Group them by month with mean value of 'AveragePrice'
grp = cali.groupby(cali['Month']).AveragePrice.mean()
print('\nGrouped Data:')
print(grp)
```